# spring security authentication issue 401 Unauthorized

Tags: spring

Need help with regard to Authentication using Spring Security. It is to authenticate REST API , there is no UI (formlogin etc..).

Configured with Authentication provider and Authentication entry point to handle exceptions. 
Below are Security Config and Authentication Provider Classes. Please check. Issue is
 1. When we invoke API with No Auth (with out credentials) - it provided valid exception with response body- "Full Authentication is required to access this resource".
 2. When we invoke API with incorrect credentials (bad username/password) - it provided only http status code as 401 with no response body.

Security Config :

```
 @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().fullyAuthenticated();   
        // http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().permitAll(); 
        http.addFilterAfter(securityFilter, BasicAuthenticationFilter.class); 
        http.exceptionHandling()
        .authenticationEntryPoint(new AuthenticationEntryPoint()); 
        http.httpBasic();
        http.csrf().disable();
   @Override
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider);
    }
}
```

Authentication Provider :

````
 @Override
 public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
     Authentication auth = null;
     try {
         auth = authenticationProvider().authenticate(authentication);
     } catch (BadCredentialsException e) {
         LOGGER.info("User Authenticated Status Active Directory 1:" + e.getMessage()); 
         throw new BadCredentialsException("Authentication Failed :" + e.getMessage()); 
     } catch (Exception e) {
         LOGGER.info("User Authenticated Status Active Directory:" + e.getMessage()); 
         throw new BadCredentialsException("Authentication Failed :" + e.getMessage());  
     }
     return auth;
 }
 ```

http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().fullyAuthenticated() - // working for No Auth but not for incorrect credentials 

http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().permitAll();  - // working for incorrect credentials but not if user provided no credentials - it is allowing all request with no basic auth details which is invalid 


I tried with different ways by using authentication failure handler , security filter bean - but no luck.  
Please advise on the above issue on how to handle.
````

Comment: -- authenticationEntryPoint(new AuthenticationEntryPoint()) - Bad Credentials exception is not throwing by this entry point though mentioned in exception handler.
--  http.addFilterAfter(securityFilter, BasicAuthenticationFilter.class) - added this filter to capture bad credentials before it is being handled by entry point class. But it is of no use, not working at all 
-- LOGGER.info("User Authenticated Status Active Directory 1:" + e.getMessage());  - It is printed in the console logs but the following exception is never thrown by this class

Comment: -- throw new BadCredentialsException("Authentication Failed :" + e.getMessage())
   This exception is never thrown from this Authentication provider class 

How we can throw exception from Authentication method from Authentication provider class, pls advise.